# Creating MySQL triggers using DataMapper

Tags: mysql, triggers, datamapper

I've been trying to search and figure this on my own, but no luck so far :(

I'd like to create MySQL triggers using DataMapper (or any other Ruby db adapter). Is this possible?

I'd really like to have the triggers become part of my code versioning (for documentation and maintenance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply execute arbitrary SQL in your migrations

```
migration 1, :create_people_table do
  up do
    execute 'CREATE TRIGGER ...'
  end
  down do
    execute 'DROP TRIGGER ...'
  end
end
```

Of course, it won't be terribly portable.

http://rubydoc.info/gems/dm-migrations/1.1.0/DataMapper/Migration:execute