# Best way to use an SQL script in Ruby Sinatra, with DataMapper, to create a simple table?

Tags: sql, ruby, sinatra, datamapper

I want to create a simple table within my Sinatra app, using DataMapper for db connections,                             using the following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `prov_abbrev` (
  `abbrev` varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `province` varchar(256) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

    INSERT INTO `prov_abbrev` (`abbrev`,`province`)
    VALUES
    ('AB','Alberta'),
    ('BC','British Columbia'),
    ('MB','Manitoba'),
    ('NB','New Brunswick'),
    ('NL','Newfoundland and Labrador'),
    ('NT','Northwest Territories'),
    ('NS','Nova Scotia'),
    ('NU','Nunavut'),
    ('ON','Ontario'),
    ('PE','Prince Edward Island'),
    ('QC','Quebec'),
    ('SK','Saskatchewan'),
    ('YT','Yukon');
```

I want to use it as a lookup table for various other models, in various apps, so it will be used quite a bit. What is the best way to do this? Would it make more sense to just setup a hash/array containing the data? Are there any benefits having the data in a table, like being able to lookup the values from within a form using js comes to mind...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use [Data Mapper Migrations gem](https://github.com/datamapper/dm-migrations): make a up-migration to create the table and then loop over a Ruby array while inserting rows. (And a simple drop table as a down-migration).

Comment: So there isn't really any way to just execute that SQL. I've just created a CSV file with the data and use ruby's built-in CSV to populate a table I've setup using DM (created fresh each time using DataMapper.auto_migrate!). I suppose this is just a more "automated" way of doing what you suggested.

Comment: Well if you already have the SQL script and are not worried about portability, you could just shell out to the mysql client, and import the SQL directly. Or you could read it line by line and execute raw SQL inside a migration [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336424/creating-mysql-triggers-using-datamapper).

Comment: Thanks for linking to that migration example, that was actually what I was originally looking for, but I have since decided that going the CSV way makes much more sense for my purpose (in fact I quickly & easily just added US state abbreviations to the CSV file).